# Version compatibility of Firefox and the latest Selenium IDE (2.9.1.1-signed)

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-ide

I visited https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

to install the latest **Selenium IDE (v 2.9.1)** in Firefox.

My **Firefox version is 54 (64-bit)**
OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 14393)

But unfortunately "Add to Firefox" button was shown disabled on the site https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

On that site NOTE was found as:
Note: Selenium IDE will NOT work on Firefox version 55 onwards. Please stay on Firefox version 54 or older.
[image]

What can I do to install Selenium IDE on FF 54?

Comment: Read this: https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/

Comment: And go to Help-->About firefox and check is your version is updated?

Comment: Good news is that "Add to Firefox" button is enabled for Firefox 54 in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/ and Selenium-IDE installation is straight forward.

Answer (score 8):

Sad but true, It is no secret by now that Selenium IDE will be deprecated. In fact, it has [already stopped working](https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/in-search-of-the-selenium-ides-successor-33bc7eaefe7f) since Firefox 55. Here are some potential replacements that you may consider applying to your project:

- [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/)
- [Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=stackoverflow)
- [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/)
- [TestProject](https://link.testproject.io/bsg)

Good luck and Good bye Legend.

Comment: Thanks Joey Rock for providing some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I think Firefox is not supported Selenium IDE after 53 or 54 version, I have read that blog

**https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/**

Comment: Does Firefox 52 support the latest Selenium IDE?

Comment: In the above blog I found "The bad news: from Firefox 55 onwards, Selenium IDE will no longer work.". That's why I used FF 54.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 55 doesn't support Selenium IDE 2.9.1. FF 54 and less are OK.

**Installation Selenium IDE on FF 54:**
1. Open Firefox 54 and visit https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/
2. Click "Download Anyway" link to download (In my case, it was selenium_ide-2.9.1-fx.xpi)

[image]

3. Open .xpi file you download in Firefox 54 -> Click Install and then Restart Now according to following interface:

[image]

Comment: "Add to Firefox" button is shown enabled in FF 54 now. So installation is straight forward. Click "Add to Firefox" button and follow the installation instruction step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues few weeks ago.Firefox version 55 doesn't support Selenium IDE. You need to downgrade your Firefox browser to Firefox version 54, 53 or below.
For doing so, please refer the link below

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Also, you need to delete all your old firefox data before installing older version because it might not work  if you don't do so.

Then finally you can add Selenium IDE and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I'm using FF 54

Comment: so, whats the problem?

Comment: I already mentioned the problem in my question. FF version: 54 but "Add to Firefox" button was disabled in the site - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

Comment: I face same issue in 54 thats why I will mention

Comment: well, i am using Firefox version 54 and IDE works. you can use much older versions like 53 or 52, it might work... rather than IDE i suggest you to use selenium webdriver..

Comment: @rhea: The two selenium flavors have different purpose. Selenium IDE is mainly used for recording tests, and Selenium WebDriver is the vast/depth use of automation test to make test flexible with various language and for cross-browser testing.

Answer (score 0):

I need to run Firefox 54 with Selenium but, like the others on this question, wasn't able to easily install Selenium. I did find a way to do this without going to a 3rd party site by copying the XPI download link (just right click on the disabled Add to Firefox button in the Firefox Add-ons page and copy the location), downloading it within Chrome or another browser, and finally just drag and drop the XPI into Firefox. That worked for me, hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, the best versions of selenium and Firefox that work better, powerful and with more options (according to my experience), are those, Firefox 54.0.1 and selenium 2.9.1. Despite they are deprecated. So I understand well your question and need.

Here you have a trick to install that Selenium version in that Firefox version, getting away the inactive add-on button:
[Download manually the selenium version 2.9.1 (as a file) and then add it manually through "Install Add-on from file" in Firefox in the section "Extensions".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQuxA.png)

This is the link to download selenium 2.9.1:
https://ui.vision/howto/getseleniumide